# Presenting a new view controller and then dismissing it, calls init() on the parent view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I am finding a very weird behaviour on my app, the structure of the view controllers is the following:

`TabBarViewController` contains:

```
- NavigationController(root is HomeViewController)
- NavigationController(root is SearchViewController)
- NavigationController(root is ProfileViewController)
```

When I am in HomeViewController, I present modally PremiumViewController

```
@objc func premiumTapped() {
    let premiumViewController = PremiumViewController(viewModel: PremiumViewModel(networkService: NetworkService(), purchasesService: PurchasesService.shared))
    navigationController?.present(premiumViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**All fine until here.**

Now I dismiss `PremiumViewController.`

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

What happens is that `HomeViewController` calles it's `init()` and `viewDidLoad()`!

How is this possible? `HomeViewController` has been existing all this time, so why it calls init again?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the `init` of `HomeViewController` and see what's calling it.

Comment: @rmaddy OMG you are the best, thank you a lot for making me look for 10th time in this breakpoint. I finally saw the issue, I was creating the view controllers in the Tabbarviewcontroller in the viewWillAppear!! Damn it! Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @rmaddy I found the issue.

To find it out, I put a breakpoint in the `init()` function that was called all the time. I found out that who was calling it was `viewWillAppear()` from the `TabbarViewController`.

The issue was that I initialise the tabbar view controller on the `viewWillAppear()` rather than on `viewDidLoad()`, which made recreate all the tab controllers every time one of the views appeared.